# Bloqueo de proyectos en netbeans (centos7)

Tags: java, linux, netbeans

tengo instalado centos 7 al cual instale netbeans y se me instala todo bien pero al momento que ingreso a netbeans me salen los proyecto bloqueados ejemplo: 
serie_fibonacci(broken). alguien sabe porque

Comment: Netbeans siempre utilizará la máscara de permisos con la que fue instalado, si has instalado netbeans como root entonces a la hora de crear proyecto sólo el root podrá hacer cambios en ellos. Deberás cambiar los permisos manualmente ya sea de los proyectos, o del netbeans en sí mismo. (Lo mejor es hacer lo último)

Comment: Como puedo cambiar los permisos ya lo estoy haciendo con el chmod pero sigue saliendo bloqueado

Answer (score 0):

Prueba hacerlo de esta manera con **sudo chown -rwxxr**  tu usuario /usr/local/netbeans-8.2 por lo regular esta es la url de netbeans